# Mousedown event on winform button on touch screen

Tags: vb.net, winforms, touchscreen, mousedown

I have a vb.net winform application with a button that starts some motors (but that could be anything) on the mouse down event.

```
Private Async Sub btnForward_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles btnForward.MouseDown
  Await _brick.DirectCommand.TurnMotorAtPowerForTimeAsync(OutputPort.B + OutputPort.C, 100, 30000, False)
End Sub

Private Async Sub btnForward_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles btnForward.MouseUp
  Await _brick.DirectCommand.StopMotorAsync(OutputPort.All, False)
End Sub
```

This works fine on my desktop PC where I am using a mouse. But this does not work on a touch screen device. Although the touching of the screen is interpreted a s a mouse click event, the mouse down event does not trigger and a prolonged touch is then interpreted as a right click. Is there a work around for this? So far all I found where suggestions to move the finger to trigger the mouse down event.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like this is an issue with your screen (or settings for your touchscreen) rather than the code. Taps on the screen should register a button click. A point of note: we found that a fly landing on the screen can activate a button press, so starting up potentially dangerous hardware using a touchscreen is not necessarily a good idea.

Comment: Thanks Matt and that is understandable. However I am hoping there is a way to enable that functionality at least while my application is running and, preferably on specific button controls.

Comment: This worked for me before where I press and hold the button slightly longer for the click event to work. It may sound lame but it did work. There is also a case of having fat fingers and the point of first touch on the touch screen is beyond the button itself. Try adding a click event and see if that fires?

Comment: @Leprechaun The click event fires, the mouse down does not. The buttons are much bigger than my finger. I believe that the mouse down not firing is by design. I need a way to override it.